# Les épées se renvoyaient l’insulte

Tags: sens, littérature

Le mot « épée » veut dire quoi dans le passage suivant:

> les fils des compagnons de Charlemagne dédaignant les compagnons de
>   Napoléon. Les **épées**, comme nous venons de le dire, se renvoyaient
>   l’insulte ; **l’épée** de Fontenoy était risible et n’était qu’une
>   rouillarde ; **l’épée** de Marengo était odieuse et n’était qu’un sabre.

Source: [Les Misérables/Tome 3/Livre 3/03](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Étant donné que j'ai du me pencher sur le chapitre dont est issu l'extrait, ce qui suit est plus une analyse de texte qu'une réponse à une question sur la langue française.

---

Comme les autres, je pensais d'abord à un combat d'épée, mais en lisant le texte il semble que c'est assez différent. Fontenoy et Marengo sont des **batailles** (une qui date de 1745 et l'autre de 1800, sous Napoléon).

Ici, l'*épée* désigne donc l'armée, la bataille, ou bien plus directement l'armement des troupes durant la bataille, difficile à dire.

À noter aussi que les soldats n'avaient pas d'épée (plutôt des fusils à baïonnette), et donc soit le mot "épée" est très figuré, soit il désigne les généraux (qui eux ont bien des épées), et donc la noblesse de l'armée. ("*L'épée de Fontenoy*" serait donc "*l'épée des généraux de la bataille de Fontenoy*").

En tout cas, "*se renvoyaient l'insulte*" signifie qu'elles étaient toutes pires les unes que les autres. Ce passage parle du fait qu'à ce moment-là, la France (et surtout la noblesse) avait perdu sa grandeur et ses repères :

> "les races historiques ayant perdu le sens de l’histoire"
>
> "On n’avait plus le sentiment de ce qui était grand, ni le sentiment de ce qui était ridicule."

Même en lisant le texte plusieurs fois, difficile de dire exactement à quoi se réfère le "*Les épées, **comme nous venons de le dire***".

La phrase la plus proche qui parle de ça est "*la noblesse des croisades conspuant la noblesse de l’empire, c’est-à-dire la noblesse de **l’épée***". L'épée serait donc bien l'empire, et par extension son armée et/ou ses généraux.

---

Le mot [*rouillarde*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouillarde) désigne quand à lui une épée rouillée, hors de service.

Comment: La [bataille de Fontenoy](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Fontenoy) s'est déroulée le 11 mai 1745. Ce n'est pas une bataille napoléonienne.

Comment: @Toto En effet, tu as raison. Du coup, pourquoi parler de batailles aussi éloignées (1745 et 1800) ? J'avais le souvenir que pendant une partie du livre Hugo parlait des batailles Napoléoniennes. Peut-être qu'il compare Marengo (qui se passe grosso modo au moment qu'il décrit) et une bataille plus ancienne pour montrer que c'est du pareil au même et que ça ne s'est pas amélioré ?

Comment: Je pense que c'est pour distinguer la noblesse royale (descendante de Charlemagne, qui s'est battue à Fontenoy) de la noblesse impériale (créée par Napoléon, qui s'est battue à Marengo).

Comment: @Toto Oui je pense la même chose. Le texte compare à plusieurs reprises la noblesse du passé (*les croisades* par exemple) à la noblesse Napoléonienne.

Comment: Par ailleurs, [rouillarde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouillarde)

Answer (score 1):

Le mot 'épée' veux dire 'épée'. C'est une personnification du mot épée.
Dans le texte il y a deux épées, une vieille épée rouillée (rouillarde) et un sabre.

l'auteur qualifie l'une d'elle de risible et l'autre de odieuse et utilise une figure de style appelé personnification.

**personnification**: La personnification est une figure de style qui consiste à attribuer des propriétés humaines à un animal ou à une chose inanimée (objet concret ou abstraction) que l'on fait vouloir, parler, agir, à qui l'on s'adresse. ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personnification))

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris :)